# Could you please convert Pine Script V.2 to V.4

Tags: pine-script

Could you please convert this `V.2` Pine script to `V.4` for me. I tried my best but I couldn't finish it.

When I tried to run this code. The error always appears starting at the line of:

> x=thisCCI >= 0 ?bufferUp:thisCCI <= 0 ?bufferDn:x[1]

```
//@version=2
study("Magic Trend",overlay=true)
CCI = input(14)
ATR = input(5)
Multiplier=input(1.5,title='ATR Multiplier')
original=input(false,title='original coloring')
colorBuy= #2DFF03 // Good sign for long trade
colorSell = #ff0346 // Good sign for short trade

thisCCI = cci(close, CCI)
lastCCI = nz(thisCCI[1])
bufferDn= high + Multiplier * sma(tr,ATR)
bufferUp= low - Multiplier * sma(tr,ATR)
if (thisCCI >= 0 and lastCCI < 0) 
    bufferUp := bufferDn[1]
if (thisCCI <= 0 and lastCCI > 0) 
    bufferDn := bufferUp[1]

if (thisCCI >= 0)
    if (bufferUp < bufferUp[1])
        bufferUp := bufferUp[1]
else
    if (thisCCI <= 0)
        if (bufferDn > bufferDn[1])
            bufferDn := bufferDn[1]

x=thisCCI >= 0 ?bufferUp:thisCCI <= 0 ?bufferDn:x[1]
swap=x>x[1]?1:x<x[1]?-1:swap[1]
swap2=swap==1?lime:red
swap3=thisCCI >=0 ?lime:red
swap4=original?swap3:swap2
plot(x,color=swap4,transp=0,linewidth=2)

bullTrendMagic = swap4 == lime and swap4[1] == red
bearTrendMagic = swap4 == red and swap4[1] == lime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted to Pine Script `v4`

```
//@version=4
study("Magic Trend", overlay=true)

CCI         = input(14)
ATR         = input(5)
Multiplier  = input(1.5,   title='ATR Multiplier')
original    = input(false, title='original coloring')
colorBuy    = #2DFF03 // Good sign for long trade
colorSell   = #ff0346 // Good sign for short trade

var float   x       = na
var float   swap    = na
var color   swap2   = na
var color   swap3   = na
var color   swap4   = na

thisCCI     = cci(close, CCI)
lastCCI     = nz(thisCCI[1])

bufferDelta = Multiplier * sma(tr,ATR)
bufferDn    = high + bufferDelta
bufferUp    = low  - bufferDelta

if (thisCCI >= 0 and lastCCI < 0) 
    bufferUp := bufferDn[1]
if (thisCCI <= 0 and lastCCI > 0) 
    bufferDn := bufferUp[1]

if (thisCCI >= 0)
    if (bufferUp < bufferUp[1])
        bufferUp := bufferUp[1]
else
    if (thisCCI <= 0)
        if (bufferDn > bufferDn[1])
            bufferDn := bufferDn[1]

x       := thisCCI >= 0 ? bufferUp : thisCCI <= 0 ? bufferDn : x[1]
swap    := x > x[1] ? 1 : x < x[1] ? -1 : swap[1]
swap2   := swap == 1 ? color.lime:color.red
swap3   := thisCCI >=0 ? color.lime : color.red
swap4   := original ? swap3 : swap2

plot(x, color=swap4, transp=0, linewidth=2)

bullTrendMagic = swap4 == color.lime and swap4[1] == color.red
bearTrendMagic = swap4 == color.red and swap4[1] == color.lime
```